# Can I use the same python socket to send images one way and strings the other?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I need help figuring out what I'm doing wrong with my python sockets.

I have made a pair of server/client programmes where the the client sends a live-feed from the camera of the Raspberry Pi it is running on to the server, which is running on a Linux laptop on the same network. This part works.

My problem is that I now want to be able to send a string back to the Raspberry Pi to control the zoom level of the image. Unlike the camera-feed, this communication does not need to be continuously happening, and it would in fact be preferable for it to only occur as needed.

Unfortunately, I have almost no experience with python sockets. I only managed to get the video-feed working thanks to a helpful YouTube video, which I then modified to work in a Tkinter window with some help from the Stack Overflow community. (The video in question is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWwZF_zVf00)

My current attempts have consisted of trying to send the string data back along the same socket connection that I am using to get the images, but I suspect that this method is probably flawed.

So my question is this: How can I get the string data back to the client that's running on the Raspberry Pi?

From what I've read, I suspect that the answer involves making a second socket connection between the two devices using threads, but when I tried putting the function that runs the image socket into a thread, the picture began to flicker wildly. **FAIR WARNING TO EPILEPTICS!**

I stripped down the programme I was working on to make this simplified version to illustrate the problem. If it were working correctly, the Z+ button would zoom in the image and print "Received String = ZOOM|0.5" to the console on the client side, while the Z- button would zoom out the image and print "Received String = ZOOM|1.0".

I'll put what I think are the relevant functions from the server and client first, and then include a full copy of the simplified version in case anyone needs to see more or wants to use this themselves, since the video-feed works quite well (if you comment out the feedback functions).

I realise that at the moment I am trying to send the string on every frame of video. This is because I had a few ideas for improvements as I was writing this post.

Sorry if this post comes across as long-winded, but this IS me trying to be concise.

**Relevant functions from the server (rearranged so that the feedback sending function is at the top of its section):**

```py
    #=====================================================================================
    def Vid_Button(self):
        if (self.myvar_vid_on == False):
            self.myvar_vid_on = True
#             comUnicate = Thread(target = self.Listen_For_Data)
#             comUnicate.start()                                    # Threading causes image to strobe.
            self.Listen_For_Data()
    
    #=====================================================================================
    ## Functions Relating To The Camera Live-Feed From The Robot:
        # (LFD = Listen For Data)
        # (These functions support the main function of this group, Listen_For_Data() )
    
    
    # Send zoom level:
    def LFD_Send_Feedback(self):
        global pos_ZOOM
        print("pos_ZOOM = " + str(pos_ZOOM))
        
        # Prepare the string to be sent:
        send_String = "ZOOM|" + str(pos_ZOOM)
        print("send_String = " + send_String)
        
        #vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        # Send the string:                       # I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO SEND THE INFORMATION!!
        self.connection_Image.send(send_String)  # I think I'm trying to send the wrong datatype here.
        #^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    
    
    # Create the server for the robot to send images to:
    def LFD_Image_Server_Create(self):
        global HOST
        global PORT
        self.server_socket = socket.socket()
        self.server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
        self.server_socket.listen(0)
    
    
    
    # Display the image from the camera live-feed in the window:
    def LFD_Display_Image(self):
        # Change the image being displayed:
        self.label__Image.image = self.img
        self.label__Image.configure(image = self.img)
        
        # Refresh the window so that the image will actually be displayed:
        self.label__Image.update()
    
    
    
    # Image acquisition loop:
    def LFD_Loop_Get_Image(self):
        while(programme_Open):
            global pos_Zoom
            
            # Raise active communication flag:
            self.myvar_comms_active = True
            
            
            # Read the length of the image as a 32-bit unsigned int:
            self.image_len = struct.unpack('<L', self.connection_Image.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
            
            # If the length is zero (i.e. no image), quit the loop:
            if not self.image_len:
                self.myvar_comms_active = False    # Lower active communication flag.
                break
            
            
            # Construct a stream to hold the image data and read the image data from the connection:
            self.image_stream = io.BytesIO()
            self.image_stream.write(self.connection_Image.read(self.image_len))
            
            
            # Extract image data:
            self.image_stream.seek(0)                         # Rewind the stream.
            self.live_feed = Image.open(self.image_stream)    # Open the stream as an image with PIL.
            self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.live_feed)     # Convert the image into a format that Tkinter can use.
            
            
            # Display image in the window:
            self.LFD_Display_Image()
            
            
            # Send zoom level to the robot:
            self.LFD_Send_Feedback()
            
            
            # Lower active communication flag:
            self.myvar_comms_active = False
    
    
    
    # Used to get a video feed from the Raspberry Pi's camera:
    def Listen_For_Data(self):
        global programme_Open
        
        try:
            # Create server:
            self.LFD_Image_Server_Create()
            
            # Accept connection from the Raspberry Pi for sending images: (Accept a single connection and make a file-like object out of it)
            self.connection_Image = self.server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')
        except:
            print("Failed To Establish Connection")
        else:
            # Indicate that the connection was established:
            print("Established Connection")
            self.Status_Label_Connected()
            
            
            # Get images from the Raspberry Pi:
            try:
                self.LFD_Loop_Get_Image()
            except struct.error:
                print("Connection Broken")
        finally:
            try:
                # This try statement fixes an error that occurs when quitting programme while the video connection is still running.
                # Without the try statement, the program would try to alter a label that no longer exists, which results in an error.
                self.Status_Label_Not_Connected()
            except:
                pass
            
            
            # Close the connection with the Raspberry Pi:
            try:
                self.connection_Image.close()
            except AttributeError:
                print("Can't close a connection that doesn't exist!")
            finally:
                self.server_socket.close()
            
            
            # Lower "Video On" flag:
            self.myvar_vid_on = False
    #=====================================================================================
```

**Relevant functions from the client:**

```py
# Create the socket connection to the control device:
def MF_Connection_Create():
    global HOST
    global PORT
    global client_socket
    global connection
    
    client_socket = socket.socket()            # Create a socket.
    client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))        # Tell the socket to talk to the control device.
    connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')  # Make a file-like object out of the connection.


# Get feedback data:
def MF_Get_Feedback():
    global connection
    global client_socket
    global level_ZOOM
    
    #vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    # Get the string:                       # THIS IS THE PART I NEED HELP WITH
    value_received = connection.recv(2048)
    #^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    
    # Display the received string:
    print("Received String = " + str(value_received))
    
    # Extract the first 4 characters of the string:
    value_split = value_received.split("|")
    
    # Update the desired setting:
    if (value_split[0] == "ZOOM"):
        level_ZOOM = float(value_split[1])
        print("ZOOM = " + str(level_ZOOM))
        camera.zoom = (0.0, 0.0, level_ZOOM, level_ZOOM)


# Stream images to the control device:
def MF_Stream_Images():
    global connection
    global camera
    global imag_Format
    
    # Construct a stream to hold image data temporarily:
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    
    # Continuously capture images in video mode:
    for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream, format = imag_Format, use_video_port = True):
        try:
            # Write the length of the capture to the stream and flush to ensure it actually gets sent:
            connection.write(struct.pack('<L', stream.tell()))
            connection.flush()
            
            # Rewind the stream and send the image data over the WiFi link:
            stream.seek(0)
            connection.write(stream.read())
            
            # Get feedback values:  (Under Development)
            MF_Get_Feedback()
        except (BrokenPipeError, ConnectionResetError):
            print("Connection Broken")
            break
        else:
            # Reset the stream for the next capture
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()
    
    # If communications are cut, write a length of zero to the stream to signal that we're done:
    connection.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))
```

**Full copy of the simplified server:**

```py
##############################################################################################
## IMPORT LIBRARIES:

# GUI Libraries:
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


# Communication Libraries:
import io
import socket
import struct


# Threading Libraries:
import _thread
from threading import Thread

##############################################################################################
## DEFINE CONSTANTS:

# WiFi connection settings:
ROBO = 'IP Address'        # Network IP address of the robot (Raspberry Pi).
HOST = 'IP Address'        # Network IP address of the laptop.
PORT = 8000                  # Port to connect to.


# Define state colours for the connection label:
conctLab_NO  = '#ff8888'
conctLab_YES = '#88ff88'


# Image size settings:
pixels_x = 640         # Width  of the images, in pixels
pixels_y = 480         # Height of the images, in pixels

##############################################################################################
## DEFINE VARIABLES:

programme_Open = True     # Flag used to help close the programme
comms_Connected = False   # Flag used to indicate if the there is a connection between the control device and the robot
pos_ZOOM = 1.0            # Zoom level of the image

##############################################################################################

class Application(tk.Frame):
    #=====================================================================================
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)  # super().__init__(master)
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.myvar_vid_on       = False
        self.myvar_comms_active = False
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.grid( sticky = tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W )   # Resize window contents when window is resized.
        self.Create_Widgets()
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #=====================================================================================
    def Create_Widgets(self):
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ## Create Window:
        top = self.winfo_toplevel()
        top.rowconfigure(    0, weight = 1 )
        top.columnconfigure( 0, weight = 1 )
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ## Create Widgets:
        
        # Image display:
        self.label__Image = tk.Label( self ) # Displays video feed.
        
        # Connection status label:
        self.label__Status = tk.Label( self, text = "Not Connected", bg = conctLab_NO, fg = "black" ) # Indicates if the video link is working.
        
        # Programme control buttons:
        self.button_Start = tk.Button( self, text = "Start Connection", fg = "black", command = self.Vid_Button    ) # Connect to camera.
        self.button_Quit  = tk.Button( self, text = "QUIT",             fg = "black", command = self.Applicat_Quit ) # Quit programme.
        
        # Zoom buttons:
        self.button_C_Zoom_In  = tk.Button( self, text = "Z+", fg = "black", command = self.PanTilt_Zoom_In  )  # Zoom in
        self.button_C_Zoom_Out = tk.Button( self, text = "Z-", fg = "black", command = self.PanTilt_Zoom_Out )  # Zoom out
        
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ## Define Layouts:
        
        # Set relative column widths within the window:
        self.columnconfigure( 0, weight = 1 )
        self.columnconfigure( 1, weight = 1 )
        
        # Set relative row heights within the window:
        self.rowconfigure( 0, minsize = pixels_y)
        self.rowconfigure( 1, weight  = 1       )
        self.rowconfigure( 2, weight  = 1       )
        self.rowconfigure( 3, weight  = 1       )
        
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ## Organise Widgets:
        
        self.label__Image.grid(      column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W )
        self.label__Status.grid(     column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W )
        self.button_Start.grid(      column = 0, row = 2,                 sticky = tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W )
        self.button_Quit.grid(       column = 0, row = 3,                 sticky = tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W )
        self.button_C_Zoom_In.grid(  column = 1, row = 2,                 sticky = tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W )
        self.button_C_Zoom_Out.grid( column = 1, row = 3,                 sticky = tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W )
        
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    #=====================================================================================
    ## Pan/Tilt Control Functions:
    
    def PanTilt_Zoom_In(self):
        print("Zoom In")
        global pos_Zoom
        pos_Zoom = 0.5
    
    
    def PanTilt_Zoom_Out(self):
        print("Zoom Out")
        global pos_Zoom
        pos_Zoom = 1.0
    
    #=====================================================================================
    ## Functions For Updating The Label Which Displays The Video Connection Status:
    
    def Status_Label_Connected(self):
        self.label__Status.configure(text = "Connected" )
        self.label__Status.configure(bg   = conctLab_YES)
    
    
    def Status_Label_Not_Connected(self):
        self.label__Status.configure(text = "Not Connected")
        self.label__Status.configure(bg   = conctLab_NO    )
    
    #=====================================================================================
    def Vid_Button(self):
        if (self.myvar_vid_on == False):
            self.myvar_vid_on = True
#             comUnicate = Thread(target = self.Listen_For_Data)
#             comUnicate.start()                                    # Threading causes image to strobe.
            self.Listen_For_Data()
    
    #=====================================================================================
    ## Functions Relating To The Camera Live-Feed From The Robot:
        # (LFD = Listen For Data)
        # (These functions support the main function of this group, Listen_For_Data() )
    
    
    # Create the server for the robot to send images to:
    def LFD_Image_Server_Create(self):
        global HOST
        global PORT
        self.server_socket = socket.socket()
        self.server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
        self.server_socket.listen(0)
    
    
    
    # Display the image from the camera live-feed in the window:
    def LFD_Display_Image(self):
        # Change the image being displayed:
        self.label__Image.image = self.img
        self.label__Image.configure(image = self.img)
        
        # Refresh the window so that the image will actually be displayed:
        self.label__Image.update()
    
    
    
    # Image acquisition loop:
    def LFD_Loop_Get_Image(self):
        while(programme_Open):
            global pos_Zoom
            
            # Raise active communication flag:
            self.myvar_comms_active = True
            
            
            # Read the length of the image as a 32-bit unsigned int:
            self.image_len = struct.unpack('<L', self.connection_Image.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
            
            # If the length is zero (i.e. no image), quit the loop:
            if not self.image_len:
                self.myvar_comms_active = False    # Lower active communication flag.
                break
            
            
            # Construct a stream to hold the image data and read the image data from the connection:
            self.image_stream = io.BytesIO()
            self.image_stream.write(self.connection_Image.read(self.image_len))
            
            
            # Extract image data:
            self.image_stream.seek(0)                         # Rewind the stream.
            self.live_feed = Image.open(self.image_stream)    # Open the stream as an image with PIL.
            self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.live_feed)     # Convert the image into a format that Tkinter can use.
            
            
            # Display image in the window:
            self.LFD_Display_Image()
            
            
            # Send zoom level to the robot:
            self.LFD_Send_Feedback()
            
            
            # Lower active communication flag:
            self.myvar_comms_active = False
    
    
    
    # Send zoom level:
    def LFD_Send_Feedback(self):
        global pos_ZOOM
        print("pos_ZOOM = " + str(pos_ZOOM))
        
        # Prepare the string to be sent:
        send_String = "ZOOM|" + str(pos_ZOOM)
        print("send_String = " + send_String)
        
        #vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        # Send the string:                       # I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO DO THIS!!
        self.connection_Image.send(send_String)  # I think I'm trying to send the wrong datatype here.
        #^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    
    
    # Used to get a video feed from the Raspberry Pi's camera:
    def Listen_For_Data(self):
        global programme_Open
        
        try:
            # Create server:
            self.LFD_Image_Server_Create()
            
            # Accept connection from the Raspberry Pi for sending images: (Accept a single connection and make a file-like object out of it)
            self.connection_Image = self.server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')
        except:
            print("Failed To Establish Connection")
        else:
            # Indicate that the connection was established:
            print("Established Connection")
            self.Status_Label_Connected()
            
            
            # Get images from the Raspberry Pi:
            try:
                self.LFD_Loop_Get_Image()
            except struct.error:
                print("Connection Broken")
        finally:
            try:
                # This try statement fixes an error that occurs when quitting programme while the video connection is still running.
                # Without the try statement, the program would try to alter a label that no longer exists, which results in an error.
                self.Status_Label_Not_Connected()
            except:
                pass
            
            
            # Close the connection with the Raspberry Pi:
            try:
                self.connection_Image.close()
            except AttributeError:
                print("Can't close a connection that doesn't exist!")
            finally:
                self.server_socket.close()
            
            
            # Lower "Video On" flag:
            self.myvar_vid_on = False
    #=====================================================================================
    ## Used To Quit The Programme:
    def Applicat_Quit(self):
        
        # Indicate that the programme is beginning to close:
        print(MyVar_Divider_String)
        print("Starting Closing Procedures")
        
        
        # Signal to the programme that it should start to close:
        global programme_Open
        programme_Open = False
        
        
        # Close the window:
        print("About To Quit Tkinter")   # Indicate that the Tkinter window is about to be destroyed.
        self.master.destroy()            # Close Tkinter window.
    #=====================================================================================

##############################################################################################
## RUN PROGRAMME:

MyVar_Divider_String = "================================"

# Signify start of programme execution:
print(MyVar_Divider_String)
print("Programme Start")
print(MyVar_Divider_String)
print("Command Log:")


# Run the Tkinter programme:
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x800")               # Set the default size of the window.
app = Application()                     # Create Application instance.
app.master.title("Window Title")        # Set the title of the window.
app.mainloop()                          # Start Application.


# Signify end of programme execution:
print(MyVar_Divider_String)
print("Programme Ended")
print(MyVar_Divider_String)

##############################################################################################
```

**Full copy of the simplified client:**

```py
##############################################################################################
## IMPORT LIBRARIES:

import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import picamera

##############################################################################################
## CONSTANTS:

## WiFi connection settings:
HOST   = 'IP Address'    # Network IP address of the laptop controlling the robot.
PORT   = 8000              # Port to connect to.
PESTER =    5              # How often the robot will attempt to connect to the controller device (in seconds).


# Camera settings:
cam_res = (640, 480)   # Camera resolution.      # cam_res = (1280, 720) # = HD
imag_Format = 'jpeg'   # Image format.

##############################################################################################
## VARIABLES:

programme_Open = True  # Used to help close the programme.
level_ZOOM     = 1.0   # Zoom level of the camera. (1.0 = no zoom)

##############################################################################################
## FUNCTIONS:     # (MF = My Function)

# Create the camera object:
def MF_Camera_Create():
    global camera
    global cam_res
    global level_ZOOM
    
    # Create camera object:
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()    # Make the camera object.
    camera.rotation   = 180         # Rotate image by 180 degrees. (Camera is mounted upsidedown)
    camera.resolution = cam_res     # Set the resolution of the image.
    camera.zoom = (0.0, 0.0, level_ZOOM, level_ZOOM)  # Set zoom level.


# Turn on the camera:
def MF_Camera_Start():
    global camera
    # Start the camera:
    camera.start_preview(alpha = 200)  # Start the camera & make preview see-through.
    time.sleep(2)                      # Let the camera warm up for 2 seconds.


# Turn off the camera:
def MF_Camera_Stop():
    global camera
    camera.stop_preview()  # Turn off the camera.


# Destroy the camera object:
def MF_Camera_Destroy():
    global camera
    camera.close()         # Destroy the camera object.




# Create the socket connection to the control device:
def MF_Connection_Create():
    global HOST
    global PORT
    global client_socket
    global connection
    
    client_socket = socket.socket()            # Create a socket.
    client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))        # Tell the socket to talk to the control device.
    connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')  # Make a file-like object out of the connection.


# Close the socket connection to the control device:
def MF_Connection_Destroy():
    global connection
    global client_socket
    
    try:
        connection.close()
    except:
        pass # Connection was already closed.
    finally:
        client_socket.close()


# Get feedback data:
def MF_Get_Feedback():
    global connection
    global client_socket
    global level_ZOOM
    
    #vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    # Get the string:                       # THIS IS THE PART I NEED HELP WITH
    value_received = connection.recv(2048)
    #^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    
    # Display the received string:
    print("Received String = " + str(value_received))
    
    # Extract the first 4 characters of the string:
    value_split = value_received.split("|")
    
    # Update the desired setting:
    if (value_split[0] == "ZOOM"):
        level_ZOOM = float(value_split[1])
        print("ZOOM = " + str(level_ZOOM))
        camera.zoom = (0.0, 0.0, level_ZOOM, level_ZOOM)


# Stream images to the control device:
def MF_Stream_Images():
    global connection
    global camera
    global imag_Format
    
    # Construct a stream to hold image data temporarily:
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    
    # Continuously capture images in video mode:
    for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream, format = imag_Format, use_video_port = True):
        try:
            # Write the length of the capture to the stream and flush to ensure it actually gets sent:
            connection.write(struct.pack('<L', stream.tell()))
            connection.flush()
            
            # Rewind the stream and send the image data over the WiFi link:
            stream.seek(0)
            connection.write(stream.read())
            
            # Get feedback values:  (Under Development)
            MF_Get_Feedback()
        except (BrokenPipeError, ConnectionResetError):
            print("Connection Broken")
            break
        else:
            # Reset the stream for the next capture
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()
    
    # If communications are cut, write a length of zero to the stream to signal that we're done:
    connection.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))




# Quit application: (In future versions, this will also shutdown the robot.)
def applicat_Quit():
    MF_Camera_Stop()      # Turn off the camera.
    MF_Camera_Destroy()   # Destroy the camera object.
    print("End Programme")
    # Add line of code to turn off the robot (Raspberry Pi).

##############################################################################################
## RUN PROGRAMME:

print("Start Programme")

MF_Camera_Create()    # Create the camera object.
MF_Camera_Start()     # Turn on the camera.


while (programme_Open):
    try:
        MF_Connection_Create()        # Create a socket connection to the control device.
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print("Could Not Connect To Control Device")
        pass
    else:
        print("Connected To Control Device")
        try:
            MF_Stream_Images()        # Stream images to the control device.
        finally:
            print("Close Connection")
            MF_Connection_Destroy()   # Close the socket connection.
    
    # Wait PESTER seconds before next attempt to connect to control device:
    time.sleep(PESTER)


# Quit application:
applicat_Quit()

##############################################################################################
```

Comment: Don't call the `makefile()` on both server and client sides.  Then you can use the socket for sending and receiving data.

Comment: you can use one socket to send and receive - but problem is when both sides (client and server) will try to send at the same time (or both sides will try to receive at the same time) because it can block all code. And this is why some people prefer two sockets in separted thread - every socket sends only in one direction so it will never try to send (receive) in both direction.

Comment: In standard servers (like WWW) server sends data only when client ask for it. When client ask for image then server send image, when client ask to zoom it then it doesn't send image but it always sends some answer - this way it always has pairs - first client send request, next server sends response. This way they never send at the same time (and never receive at the same time) but it sends in two directions.

Comment: @furas  
So I would be sending something back on every frame, but most of the time that thing would just tell the client "no change needed". Do I have that right?

Comment: @acw1668 What should I put instead of "makefile()"? Also, will I need to change anything else to do this?

Comment: In client side, try changing `value_received = connection.recv(2048)` to `value_received = client_socket.recv(2048)`.  In server side, try changing `self.connection_Image = self.server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')` to `self.client_socket, self.client_addr = self.server_socket.accept()` and `self.connection_Image = self.client_socket.makefile('rb')`.  Then change `self.connection_Image.send(send_String)` to `self.client_socket.send(send_String)`.

Comment: @acw1668  I get this error on the server side:  line 241, in LFD_Send_Feedback
    self.client_socket.send(send_String)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @acw1668  Fixed it. I had to add .encode() and .decode(). Thanks for your help, my problem is solved.